# Is this table possible in html?

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible to have 1 table next to each other? I know that sounds confusing so I made a picture:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Table rows without border should be all you need?

Comment: looking at your image, I would say it's the same table. Are you trying to align objects with tables?

Comment: @David I'm trying to have 1 table on the leftside and rightside without the need of 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you could achieve your request (and won't even need HTML5) adding two more columns and using a colpadding to a single table.

```
<table cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td>Description#1</td><td><img src="..."/></td>
    <td>Description#2</td><td><img src="..."/></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

See also the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzpe030v/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it..with

```
display: inline-block;
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nhpp9fr5/)

Comment: You're using two tables, I just need 1 table, like two sides with 1 table

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest solution would be to put 2 smileys and their description in one row and then style it like that:

```
   td:nth-child(odd) {
     width:100px;
   }
   tr:nth-child(odd) {
     background:#D9F4FC;
   }
```

Here is the example:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nhpp9fr5/4/)

Of course you can change the styling as you want.
Has that solved your question?